# Add ODBC connection to all users

Tags: .net, odbc, windows-server-2012, terminal-services

I have a Windows 2012 Server with a .NET application. The application need an ODBC connection to a database to run.

I have to setup to all users the ODBC connection, but i have around 100 diferent users.

Is there any way to create the connection to all users at the same time?

I have to configure this to all users profile, not in the application.

[image]

**Edit:**

After reading a bit, i have created a "system DSN" instead of a "user DSN" but the application can't connect to the DB. Only work if the ODBC is created in "user DSN". Is there any way to change it on the application?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean create a DSN?

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more on what you need Fernando. Do you need the connection created in the application?

Comment: No. I have to setup this on all users profile. https://gyazo.com/0417526e9757ae7da3dfbb4aa7d5bd89

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be available across users, you add the connection to ***System DSN*** and then it will be available regardless of the user logged into the local machine.

Comment: I have already add the connection to System DSN, but the application does not work with it. Is necesary to diference in the Conecction string if the application should use a System DSN instead of a User DSN?

Comment: I would recommend posting the code that you are using to make the connection in your application as well as any error that currently appears.